# How to get status bar height in corona sdk?

Tags: coronasdk

If it's disabled, how do I know its height?

Answer (score 1):

You can get statusbar height by using -

local statusBarHeight = display.statusBarHeight

"statusBarHeight" will store its height.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE : New Method...**

```
display.topStatusBarContentHeight
```

This [method](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/topStatusBarContentHeight.html) will also return the value of the status bar in *'content pixels'* and is to be used in replacement of the old and now deprecated method *'statusBarHeight'* - the key difference being it now supports Android.

**Now Deprecated...**

```
display.statusBarHeight
```

This [method](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/statusBarHeight.html) will allow you to read the value of the status bar height in *'content pixels'* though it is exclusive to 'iOS Devices' on Android devices it will return an incorrect value of `0` regardless of the height of the status bar.

Comment: Is it avaliable by API? In other phones it may differ.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no API for determining the height of the status bar. Out of interest what do you need to know this for?

Answer (score 0):

**Status Bar Height = display.actualContentHeight - display.contentHeight**

[image]